# External Monitor's USB ports don't work

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, display, mouse, thunderbolt

I have connected an external monitor to my macbook pro through a thunderbolt vga adapter. The monitor has several USB ports on it and if I plug a mouse or keyboard into them, they will not work. Is there a fix for this?

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to connect a USB cable (probably A/B) from the monitor to your laptop.

Comment: Yep, this is it. VGA can't transfer USB signals, and monitors with VGA, HDMI, DisplayPort or DVI require a separate USB cable to act as a USB hub.  A Thunderbolt monitor can offer USB ports without an extra cable.

Answer (score -6):

Before assuming that their is a problem with your device.  Some P.C's Require a manaul download of a driver. Which can be found Apple web sight.Original cable for your device is a must. If you have a cable for a camera device with the apple plug should be saficient. Sometimes additional driver to communicate with manufactures is also required for image or file output. Off brand cables are no good.